# Comparing two strings to see if they are rotation

Tags: c++, c, string

Rotation means one string is created from moving the other string one or more bits to the right. For example abc and cab are rotation, abcd and bacd are not rotation. 
I wrote the code below however it's failed to pass the last one test case (don't know what it is). Could anyone give me some hints about where goes wrong or is there any more efficient algorithm:

```
    int isLetterInWord(char c, char* word)//find first letter in the word which is equal to c
    {
        int len = strlen(word);
        for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        {
            if(c==word[i])
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int isRotation(char* word1, char* word2)
//check if word1 and word2 are rotation. if so return 1 otherwise -1
    {
        if(word1 == NULL && word2 == NULL)
            return 1;
        int len1 = strlen(word1);
        int len2 = strlen(word2);
        if(len1!= len2)
            return -1;
        for(int i=0; i<len1; ++i)
        {
            int pos = isLetterInWord(word1[i], word2);
            if(pos == -1)
                return -1;
            else
            {
                int p1 = i, p2 = pos;
                int cnt=0;
                while(cnt<len1)
                {
                    if(word1[p1++]!=word2[p2++])
                        break;
                    if(p1==len1)p1=0;
                    if(p2==len2)p2=0;
                    cnt++
                }
                if(cnt==len1)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: look at the test case that is failing to see what it is.

Comment: You don't know the test case where your code fails, so I assume that it is for a coding competition. The error may as well be in reading the strings to compare, maybe you hit a size limit or forget to cater for spaces. There's also the possibility of time-out on long strings; your solution isn't the most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another algorithm of solving this question is as follow:
Lets say first string is str1 and need to check whether str2 is rotation of str1.
The algorithm is as follow:

```
concatanate str1 to str1. Lets call it str3.
Now check whether str2 is a sub-string of str3.
If str2 is sub-string of str3 then it is a rotation of str1 otherwise not.
```

Please find the function to check rotation of a string:

```
int Rotations(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int size1   = strlen(str1);
  int size2   = strlen(str2);
  char *temp;
  void *ptr;
  if (size1 != size2)
  return 0;
  temp   = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size1*2 + 1));
  temp[0] = '\0';
  strcat(temp, str1);
  strcat(temp, str1);
  ptr = strstr(temp, str2);
  free(temp);
  if (ptr != NULL)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(word1==NULL&&word2==NULL)
```

This should be

```
if(word1==NULL||word2==NULL)
```

Not gone through your logic.

Answer (score -1):

**Overview:**  Find first char matching char in string, Then perform xor on string, Till end of minimum length string, This way you can find whether string are rotation string of each other

**Pre-Condition:** Length of both strings are equal, As already stated above answers

*Step 1:*   Find first matching char in both string notice `pos`(position) of char in the first string.

*Step 2:*   Now perform xor on first string from `pos` to the end of first string, With substring with same length from the second string.

*Step 3:*  If result xor is 0 means First part matches of the string matched, And proceed to match remaining part(substring), Which is first char in the first string to char at `pos-1`, And substring from second string from `pos+1` to end of string, Then perform same xor on them,

*Step 4:*  If that matches then exit with sucess, And if does not match then find next matching `char` in first string, and repeat from step 2, until reaches end of the first string

Comment: How is xoring and checking for zero better than comparing chars straight away? Especially as xoring requires an additional string or backpatching. Also, the OP has already a working, if inefficient solution. The queston is to point out the failing in an unknown test case in his code.

Comment: Xor is logical operation, So its performed in minimum CPU cycles

Comment: A `JPE` instruction is always going to be faster than an `XOR`followed by a `JPE`.